# Generating a set of random variates from Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Say I am not allowed to use built-in PoissonDistribution, which means I should generate 100 random numbers first, and then with these 100 random numbers to generate 100 random variates from Poisson with rate 2, how to use inverse transform method?

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Random_drawing_from_the_Poisson_distribution . You say _how to use inverse transform method?_ but this requires the `PoissonDistribution`'s CDF.

Comment: ^ directly applying inverse-transform-sampling will be awkward because you'll have to find an inverse for `GammaRegularized[1 + Floor[x], λ]`. However, see the method _algorithm poisson random number (Junhao, based on Knuth)_ at the bottom of that article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly translating the Wikipedia article linked in the comments:

```
poissonRandomNumber[λ_] := 
 Module[{L = Exp[-λ], k = 0, p = 1, u},
  While[p > L,
   ++k;
   p = p*RandomReal[];
   ];
  Return[k - 1]]

Histogram[Table[poissonRandomNumber[10], 20000]]
```

[image: poisson histogram]